# Token has expired when the page is refreshed

Tags: node.js, angular, express, jwt

I got some issue here. I configured authentication using JWT to authenticate user with token. Then I set up unauthenticated users not to be able to access pages that need authentication with AuthGuard. The user token saved on local Storage, but when I refreshed the page or moved to another directory like "localhost:4200/another_directory" by typing on address bar, the token was expired and I need to log in again even though the token is stored in local storage. But, when I moved to another directory by link that was set, it worked (the token doesn't expire and no need to log in). Anybody can help me?
I configured the login back end like this:

```
router.post('/login', (req,res) =>{
    if(!req.body.username){
        res.json({success:false, message:"No Username was provide"});
    }else{
        if(!req.body.password){
            res.json({success:false, message:'No password was provided'});
        }else{
            User.findOne({username:req.body.username.toLowerCase()}, (err,user) =>{
                if(err){
                    res.json({success:false, message:err});
                }else{
                    if(!user){
                        res.json({success:false, message:'Username not found'});
                    }else{
                        const validPassword = user.comparePassword(req.body.password);
                        if(!validPassword){
                            res.json({success:false, message:'Password incorrect'});
                        }else{

                            const token = jwt.sign({userId:user._id}, config.secret, {expiresIn:'24h'});

                            res.json({success:true, message:'Success!', token:token, user:{username:user.username}});
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }
});
```

then, I configured the authentication middleware like this

```
router.use((req,res,next) =>{
    const token = req.headers['authorization'];
    if(!token){
        res.json({success:false, message:'No token provided'});
    }else{
        jwt.verify(token, config.secret, (err,decoded) =>{
            if(err){
                res.json({success:false, message:'Token invalid: ' + err});
            }else{
                req.decoded = decoded;
                next();
            }
        })
    }
});
```

and this is my auth.service.ts

```
  authToken:any;
  user:any;
  options:any;
  redirectUrl:any;

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
  ) { }

  createAuthenticationHeader(){
    this.loadToken();
    let header = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'authorization': this.authToken
    });

    this.options = {
      headers: header
    }
  }
  login(user:any){
    return this.http.post(this.domain + 'authentication/login', user);
  }
  storeUserData(token:string, user:any){
    localStorage.setItem('token', token);
    localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
    this.authToken = token;
    this.user = user;
  }
  isLoggedIn(){
    const helper = new JwtHelperService();
    return helper.isTokenExpired(this.authToken);
  }
```

this is my auth.guard.ts

```
redirectUrl:any;


constructor(
    private authService:AuthService,
    private router:Router
  ){}

  canActivate(
    router:ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state:RouterStateSnapshot
  ):boolean{
    if(!this.authService.isLoggedIn()){
      return true;
    }else{
      this.redirectUrl = state.url;
      this.router.navigate(['/login']);
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Comment: I don't see any call to `storeUserData`

Comment: It done guys. It happened because I did not set authToken variable with the user token stored in local storage. Then when I set that, it can worked as expected. Happy coding guys. :D